# undefined method `take' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x00000107609598>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to select all profiles where a.blocked?(p) returns false!

However I am getting an error.

## in a method in model

```
p = self.find_by_email(email)

all.find_by { |a| a.blocked?(p) }.order('random()')
```

## error

```
undefined method `take' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x00000107609598>
```

Comment: can you provide more information on the code. It looks like a.blocked? is custom defined in your code.

Comment: it is! and the map returns an array of true or false values, [I am pretty sure..] ..also blocekd is from the amistad gem!

Comment: I know ruby has enumerable module which has 'take'. Going by the error. One example could be %w[a b c d].take(3) => ["a", "b", "c"]. I use backports when using older version of ruby using require 'backports/1.8.7/enumerable/take'.. Not sure if it is of any help to you.

Comment: What is your Ruby version?

Comment: version 2.1.1! @Pavan

Answer (score 0):

`find_by` does not take a block, but rather conditions in the form of a hash, array, or string. See the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

If you can't replicate `blocked?` in SQL, you'll have to do the filtering in Ruby like:

```
all.find_all { |a| a.blocked?(p) }.shuffle
```

Because that's doing the filtering and sorting in Ruby rather than SQL, it will be slower.